# Scala-IDE/IntelliJ :: Template support for Scalate, Play, etc

Tags: scala, ide, template-engine

**EDIT2**
Scala IDE now has template support with type inference, semantic highlighting, etc. for the Play framework as of v3.0 of the IDE. Same deal with routes file(s), woohoo ;-)

Not sure about Play, Scalate, or other template engine support in IntelliJ.

**EDIT**
Play 2.0 is unbelievably awesome, so much so that the lack of IDE support is fairly minor -- all the heavy lifting is done via model, controller and javascript (coffeescript + datatables) layers; view layer consists of simple xhtml skeletons, so no biggie not having, for example, autocomplete for Scala code -- your app won't compile if there are errors regardless, so you're safe to boot ;-)

If and when template layer IDE support comes it will be a welcome addition, but nothing that I personally am losing any sleep over...

**ORIGINAL**
Just discovered something last night after a couple months of relative joy hacking around in Scala-IDE for Eclipse:

There appears to be NO template layer support whatsoever (code completion, syntax highlighting, etc.).  This is the case even for TypeSafe's new adoptee, Play 2.0, with its Razor style @ syntax. Scalate, same boat, none of the uber cool options (jade, ssp, scaml) are detected by the IDE.

This is not just the case for Scala-IDE mind you, seems to be a given with IntelliJ as well, roughly 2 years after requesting template support:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-1876

Obviously, must be difficult to implement, otherwise we'd have built-in or plugin support for the main templating languages. Kind of groping in the dark here, the best I've been able to do is have the IDE interpret the .jade extension as Scala code, which highlights scala keywords in a pleasant light-blue and nothing else, no hovers, code completion, arrgggghhh ;-)

What are the alternatives here?? Coming from Groovy/Grails I have gotten spoiled by excellent IDE support for straight scala code and would dearly love to have that tied in with the template layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play 2.0 support is planned for IntelliJ IDEA 12, some of Scala template languages are also planned for IntelliJ IDEA 12.

Comment: +1, ok, thanks, still depressed, IntelliJ 11 just came out, v12 is what months away? Looks like one just hammers away in the dark, refreshes the browser and hopes for the best.  Feels like PHP before there was IDE support...

Comment: In fairness, it is a punishing task to keep up with the overabundance of template languages.  In theory this should be easier since the templates are actually Scala code, but it needs some special tweaks since there are different auto-imports than Scala script and some other namespace differences.  In theory it should be similar to Jason's build.sbt support though.

Comment: Right, clearly not a priority regardless, as there is ZERO support in either Scala IDE or IntelliJ for Scalate and Play template engines, presumably the go-to choices for Scala web development (Scalate was released 3 or 4 years ago to put in perspective the bottom-of-the-barrel that is IDE template engine support). For Scala, what is the overabundance of template languages, btw?? Unless you're talking FreeMarker, Site Mesh, and Java-based engines, I only know Scalate and Play for Scala