# ssp files (Scalatra) Auto Indentation not working in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, indentation, scalatra

I am writing scala and ssp files in Intellij, i want Intellij to auto-Indent my code. While it is working for scala files but it doesn't work for ssp files.

Is there any way we can configure IntelliJ to auto-indent these files also.

or is there any ssp editor available online ?

Comment: See [Scala-IDE/IntelliJ :: Template support for Scalate, Play, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9392924/2390083). I have searched one month ago as well, without luck. In our case it was possible to use JSPX, because we have no code left in the page, so nothing is lost (controller and services are written in Scala). Using a customer El resolver works fine to support Scala iterables and options.

Comment: Thnx...explored some more...got that support not yet available [Source :youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-1876?projectKey=SCL] ...thought found textmate which has scalete bundle available for mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no support available for scalate in Intellij.

For now you can use Textmate with [this bundle](https://github.com/scalate/Scalate.tmbundle). Working for me.